# Are there any works discussing planetary bodies being forms of life?

Tags: planet, life

I'm searching for works or individuals that consider and discuss the idea of planetary bodies being considered stand alone living creatures, rather than objects either capable or incapable of supporting life.  Anyone familiar with something along those lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up [Gaia hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_hypothesis), [James Lovelock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Lovelock#Gaia), and [Lynn Margulis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynn_Margulis#Gaia_hypothesis).

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for, thanks!